# How to compute the maximum combination that is composed from amongst m objects, each having n alternatives?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Assume there are m objects, each having n types of alternatives and each alternative having a value and a weight. Different objects have different alternatives. The final objective is to select one alternative for each object in order to maximize the total value of the combination. This combination is constrained by the total weight of the permutation not exceeding by a given constant. How do you do this?

Regarding the alternatives, the function f(weight) = value of the value and weight is a monotonically increasing function, although the exact function is not known. This function f might be same or different(unknown) for different objects.

I understand that if solved in a rigid CS manner, this should take O(n^m).This is especially very big for m > 70 and n > 50.

However, this is a real world engineering problem, and some degree of accuracy can be traded for a faster running time. An alternative I have been thinking of is to try to approximate the function of the alternatives for each object, using a learning model. Once we get f', we put these functions in a mathematical equation to get the following computational problem. We then use Lagrange's Multipliers to solve the following:-

[image: optimization problem]

Is my current solution wrong? Am I overthinking this and is there a simpler solution present? Would you solve this in a different manner? Can a special Data Structure be used in combination with my approach to make it faster?

Comment: Please tell me if this question is suited better to another stackexchange site like cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you use frameworks developed by others or you have to develop your own solution? If you can use others work try MOEA (http://moeaframework.org/) it's a framework for solving multi-objective optimization problems.

Comment: @A2H I have no problems in using other frameworks/solutions developed by other people. Checking out the framework that you have provided.

Comment: @A2H The framework looks good, but I am not sure about the speed.

Comment: I have tried this framework to solve the Knapsack problem, yours looks very similar to it, with 2 knapsacks and each knapsack having 100 items (each item has a weight and a profit). It worked pretty fast, solved the problem in seconds, no later than a minute.

Comment: @A2H wow, that is fast. I am actually working on this in PHP, so integration with Java might be a little problematic, but doesn't matter if it is fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be dynamic programming solutions to this, if you are happy to scale and round the weights to make them small integers.

After doing this create a table that gives, for each i and each weight w, table[i][w] = the maximum value that can be achieved using the first i objects and having total weight at most w.

You can work out the results for i=n+1 from the results for i=n - just consider all the possible choices for the n+1th object and look at the best answers for the first n objects.

Also keep enough book-keeping, such as the best choice for each combination of i and n, so that when you have worked out the best value possible using all the objects and the actual weight constraint you can trace back to find the right answer (actually in this case if you keep the table of weights I think you can back track fairly easily without keeping extra notes).

The cost of this is the number of objects times the number of choices for each object times the maximum total weight - so you can see there is a tradeoff between getting accurate answers with fine divisions and large total weights and fast answers with rough divisions and small total weights, where you divide by a large number before rounding the weights.

Comment: I don't understand why DP will make a difference in this case. There is no re-computation in the normal method too. Worst case scenario is trying all combinations which is O(n^m), since you have to try **all** the combinations. From what I can see, you can't skip that. Could you please explain the solution and its complexity in more detail?

For an object 'i', you still have to try all of the alternatives 'n'' for that particular object. I would like to repeat: **each object** has 'n' alternatives. eg: object 1 has 'n' alternatives, object '2' has a separate set of 'n' alternatives,and so on.

Comment: I suggest you look at psuedo-polynomial solutions to the Knapsack problem, because they use much the same mechanism as I suggest - see e.g. http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall11/rec/rec21_knapsack.pdf. Suppose the max weight is 10000, n=10, m=100 then n*m*w=1E7 but n^m=1E100.

Comment: Oh yes. I should've known that. Quite correct. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent Solution. Especially this: _"if you are happy to scale and round the weights to make them small integers."_

Was able to scale down from ~300 minutes with a process running on a single-core on Intel i3 to 50 seconds, by dividing by 100, which in my particular context is quite acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a problem that is well suited to throw at a Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) solver. The MIP model can look like:

[image]

Some notes:

- This is not exactly a knapsack problem, as we have two constraints (a knapsack problem usually deals with just one constraint).
- The method with Lagrangian multipliers is usually not applicable when the model contains discrete variables. In my model x is a binary variable, i.e. it can only assume the values zero or one.
- I don't assume some function that maps weight to value. I just assume you have weight and value data for each object/alternative. (If you have a function to compute the value for a given weight, you can apply that function to pre-compute the values; i.e. before we solve the problem).

Comment: Any ideas on how much time this would take?

Comment: For the above example (10 objects each with 5 alternatives) the open source solver [CBC](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) takes 0.1 seconds on my somewhat old laptop.

Comment: Quite fast. Will be trying this. Thanks.